# How to get Notify when destination is reached in Google maps iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Im using Google maps API To draw Route between two Points.
Here my destination location is fixed, Origin which is driver location is variable as the driver moves on. Now I want to get notify when driver reached destination. How can i do this.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In CLLocation didUpdateLocation delegate, check the distance(airial distance) between current location and your destination location. If the distance is very less(say 5 to 7 meters) you can say that the user has reached its destination. Hope it helps.